# Adding image to HTML table breaks the table

Tags: html, css

When adding an extra row to an html table (three columns of images) - adding a new logo causes the table to break and the first row expands to about 900px wide. Any ideas what could cause this drastic change?

(1000 Lines may be a bit much, so I'll add a sample of how the code looks down the entire table.)

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p>
<img alt="Safelok" src="http://www.optrafair-london.co.uk/g/2014/logo/hilco_10_safelok_logo.jpg" style="width: 85px; height: 57px;" /></p>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<br />
<a href="http://www.optrafair-london.co.uk/Exhibitor/SPECSAVERS-OPTICAL-SUPERSTORES-LTD" target="_blank"><img alt="Specsavers" src="http://www.optrafair-london.co.uk/g/2014/logos/specsavers_resized.jpg" style="width: 122px; height: 50px;" /></a></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<img alt="Ziggi" src="http://www.optrafair-london.co.uk/g/2014/logos/capitol_ziggi.jpg" style="width: 126px; height: 62px;" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now I know that the combined pixel width of each image doesn't exceed the content boundary (including padding), and there's no associated CSS attached to the images that adds padding or something unknown - but when an Image is added - this happens:
http://www.optrafair-london.co.uk/page.cfm/Link=25/t=m/

Comment: Rather than rip a fragment from a big file can you make a minimal, but complete example instead that succinctly illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code table contains an image which has a size more than the `table` When you don't mention the column `width` explicitely, the HTML leaves it to the browser. When you specifically mention the `width` and try to put a image of bigger size then the `HTML` table make some drastic changes -  it may result from what you are facing to even worse.

It is a good practice to hard bond your `HTML` elements with proper `CSS`. Adding to it, when you are designing a webpage, then you don't put a big image in a small area. If, you will search for `stackoverflow` logo then, you'll find it in different size, this is how it is done.

- You calculate the `pixel` of the layout.
- transform your image to the size.
- Put the image in proper place.

**It is never a good practice to put images of whatever size you want, at whatever place you want.**

---

Comment: Thanks Veer - but I've checked the widths of all the images down the table, and there's nothing that exceeds the content area that I can see. (Including padding)